# How to print lines from two file according to lines numbers stored in a third file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-processing

I know that to print lines of a file, I can use cat, tail, head or grep etc. But my problem is a bit complex for me. I couldn't figure it out.

I have two files and I want to print lines from these two file side by side if the line number is exist in third file.

For example let's say my first two file as follows:

File A:

```
FileA first sentence
FileA second sentence
FileA third sentence
```

File B:

```
FileB BBfirst sentence
FileB BBsecond sentence
FileB BBthird sentence
```

and Lets  File C be as follows:

File C:

```
    3
    1
```

So, I want to print as followings:

```
   FileA third sentence     FileB BBthird sentence
    FileA first sentence    FileB BBfirst sentence
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk to rescue:

**Solution 1st:** Where I am taking highest value of digit in File_C and then from filea and fileb storing values into an array, at last traversing through that array.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];len=len>$0?len:$0;next} (FNR in a){array[FNR]=array[FNR]?array[FNR] OFS $0:$0} END{for(j=1;j<=len;j++){if(array[j]){print array[j]}}}' fileC  fileA fileB
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0];
  len=len>$0?len:$0;
  next
}
(FNR in a){
  array[FNR]=array[FNR]?array[FNR] OFS $0:$0
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=len;j++){
    if(array[j]){
      print array[j]
}
}
}
' fileC  fileA fileB
```

Output will be as follows.

```
FileA first sentence FileB BBfirst sentence
FileA third sentence FileB BBthird sentence
```

**Solution 2nd:** Here I am not using any maximum digit concept from filec, simply saving elements as per their occurrence into array and resetting variable's value whenever a very first line comes for filea and fileb so that we could save some cycles of for loop(which we couldn't in my solution 1st).

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
 a[$0];
 next
}
FNR==1{
 i=""
}
(FNR in a){
 ++i;
 array[i]=array[i]?array[i] OFS $0:$0
}
END{
 for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
  if(array[j]){
    print array[j]
}
}
}
' file_c  file_a file_b
```

Output will be as follows.

```
FileA first sentence FileB BBfirst sentence
FileA third sentence FileB BBthird sentence
```